# How can I make a code that will check if a string isn't a number

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

The question says it all

What I tried to do was

```
if (textbox1.Text != int)
{
     MessageBox.Show ("This is not a proper number.")
}
```

I use a button to start the command.
I am new to C# so excuse such a possibly easy

Comment: Note that C# is case-sensitive - even if the rest of your code had worked, this would be wrong because you're not using the right case for the `Text` property, or `MessageBox.Show`.

Comment: I submitted this from my phone so I wasn't able to do everything properly

Comment: In future, I'd suggest waiting until you're at a computer where you can write a good question, taking plenty of time over it. I find when I ask a question it rarely takes me less than twenty minutes or half an hour to make sure it's as good as it can be. I wouldn't even *think* of doing it on a phone.

Comment: Sorry, it won't be done again, I'm always short on time and squeeze things together as much as I can. It won't be done again though.

Comment: @JonSkeet: To be fair, the questions you might ask on Stack Overflow are not even in the same league as most questions.  The only people qualified to answer yours are Eric Lippert, and maybe Marc Gravell.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: But surely everyone asks questions which are hard *for them* - if you haven't tried for a little while, you haven't done enough research, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet: At least I could understand this one. :)

Answer (score 9):

This will get the number for you and tell you if it's not valid.  Also it won't throw an exception if it's not valid. It'll just return false.

```
int i;

if(!int.TryParse("Your_String_To_Try_And_Parse", out i)) {
    MessageBox.Show("Not a number");
}
```

Now the drawback to this is that it will tell you if it's an integer not a decimal etc. so 5.5 is not valid.

Answer (score 5):

Call [`int.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) and evaluate the returned result.

Answer (score 0):

in this i am performing addition of no ad if i enter string then it will get concatinated

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool chk,chk1;
            int chkq;
            chk = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out chkq);
            chk1 = int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out chkq);
            if (chk1 && chk)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Is number");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not a number");
            }
        }
```